# What permissions do I need on SQL Server to add a user to the db_datareader role?

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to create a user through the front end of my application and my user currently been given db_accessadmin and db_securityadmin roles on the database. However I'm getting the following error message

> cannot alter the role 'db_datareader' because it does not exist or you
>   do not have permission

What is the minimum permission required at database level to be able to add users to this role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to assign logins to database fixed roles, one needs to be member of the `db_owner` fixed database role, and been member of the `db_securityadmin` is not enough. (from [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Security002.htm))